# Is it possible to change the values of listview in lightning:listview?

Tags: aura

Please check the following code snippet:

```
 <lightning:listView
      objectApiName="Contact"
      rows="10"
      showSearchBar="true"
      showActionBar="true"
      enableInlineEdit="true"
      showRowLevelActions="true"
    />
```

I'm using this default listview to fetch Contact data. But, I want to show specific records of Contact object, suppose I've recordId of the specific records. Is this possible?

For example, I want to show 3 specific records from Contact, not all of them. This listview fetches all the records, which I don't want. I don't want to create a custom component, have to use this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you have a list view with those 3 records, you can do it.

With `lightning:listView`, you can show only a predefined view. If you are looking at passing record Id's dynamically then you actually don't want or are not looking for a list view but just a data table with those 3 records and additional sorting/searching functionalities which can be achieved custom code or maybe some app exchange product.

There are other workarounds like:

- Creating list views on the fly (Too much effort, code, and cleanup required).
- Create Dummy parent object and tag the record to one of them and creating a list view (Too much effort, code, and cleanup required).